# How can I find out the RGB color of my object in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uicolor

I have a button in the storyboard, I gave it a color magnesium. I am doing some programming on the button which will change its color on certain situations.

I like the original color of the button in the storyboard and I want to return back to that color at some event.

Now the problem is that color I am using doesn't have a text name (yellowcolor, purplecolor) in UIColor and I can't find the RGB values from the storyboard color picker.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set a UIView (or else) with magnesium background color, retrieve the color by code, and you'll get the RGB.

Comment: What you mean by 'A text name' ?

Comment: common color names like redcolor, yellowcolor etc..

Comment: @Larme yes that is the solution i am using now, but surely there must be some where in the storyboard showing the color of the items.

Comment: deleting the tag was pointless, I wanted the answer to be in **Xcode**

Comment: If you answered you own question then please select it as an answer. Because you found the correct solution for you. Cheers..!!

Comment: You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Comment: It's my bad. I forgot. Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xcode->Select Object->Attributes Inspector->Text Color->Other->Color Sliders->Dropdown Menu->RGB Sliders

Answer (score 31):

Follow this screen shot. I am on Windows 8 right now so i just edited the picture but it will certainly give you the way to achieve what you want.

(I combined two DIFFERENT images. So don't freak out. Sorry.)

[image]

Comment: its cute that the answer i've been searching for 3 hours comes 10 mins after i found it..

Comment: It happened with me too. Lots of thing in Xcode are beautifully designed that sometimes we just don't get it. (Because of the Windows bad habits) !!! @Esq

Comment: i honestly think that xcode sucks as an ide. but the storyboard part of it is kinda awesome, i knew there was another way other than coding to get these info

Comment: It's good to hear honest opinion. I've used VisualStudio (All of them !!), Eclipse, Netbeans by my self but, i find Xcode the best.@Esq

Comment: well personal choices :)
i think objective-c as a language sucks aswell btw :P
but ios products are pretty good, in android development i liked the development phase but not the product. ios it is the opposite the development phase isnt fun, but the product that comes out satisfies you

Comment: Yes. Personal choices.. :D @Esq

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to get the RBG from UIColor:

```
CGFloat red = self.btn.backgroundColor.CIColor.red;
    CGFloat blue = self.btn.backgroundColor.CIColor.blue;
    CGFloat green = self.btn.backgroundColor.CIColor.green;
    CGFloat alpha = self.btn.backgroundColor.CIColor.alpha;
```